# Rails application stored on heroku memory leak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memory-leaks

I have a Rails application that runs on heroku server. recently I found out that I have a memory leak (R14 memory quota exceeded error on heroku - the app uses more then 500 megabyte RAM).
I tried to read heroku article about memory leaks(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use) and some random articles but I didn't find a solution.
How do you recommend me to find out where the problem is ?

I use ruby 2.2.4 and rails 4.2.5

Comment: What have you done so far?